# Freeswitch In Windows 11 with visual Code 2017 or 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, freeswitch, unimrcp

I want to run git freeswitch library in my local machine (windows 11) in visual studios 2017 or 2022. So, is that anyone know how to do. Please Help me out.

Comment: The installation instructions are here: [https://github.com/signalwire/freeswitch/blob/master/INSTALL](https://github.com/signalwire/freeswitch/blob/master/INSTALL) looking at the project you have a better chance at getting it to work in VSCode with MinGW than you do with Visual Studio with msvc. It looks like its designed for linux or a POSIX os. I guess you could  use also WSL in Visual Studio.

Comment: Correction I found this file which looks like msbuild support: [https://github.com/signalwire/freeswitch/blob/master/msbuild.cmd](https://github.com/signalwire/freeswitch/blob/master/msbuild.cmd)

Comment: Also if you don't want to compile it yourself I found these binary downloads; [https://files.freeswitch.org/windows/installer/x64/](https://files.freeswitch.org/windows/installer/x64/)